# Getting Results in Horizontal way in oracle

Tags: oracle

I wrote query

```
select s_id from emp
where s_inv=12
```

i got results in this manner

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

but i want it in this format

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need your result in a single column, you can use [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm#SQLRF30030):

```
with emp(s_id, s_inv) as
(
    select 1, 12 from dual union all
    select 2, 12 from dual union all
    select 3, 12 from dual union all
    select 4, 12 from dual union all
    select 5, 12 from dual
)
select listagg(s_id, ' ') within group (order by s_id)
from emp
where s_inv = 12
```

If you need to build many columns on the same row, you should first define how many columns will your result have

Comment: Upvoted because this correctly answers the question given (where the OP doesn't ask for rows to be columns or for any data to pivot).  I'd upvote a second time for the clear working code example if it were possible.